# Show multiple UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone

I have two UIActionSheets which I want to show at the same time

```
[action1 showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
[action2 showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
```

the problem is that the first UIActionSheet answers the clicks, which is behind the second one which is frontmost and visible.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just implemented a flow where it is not necessary to open several UIActionSheets at the same time.